# captcha plugin for struts 2

Tags: struts2, captcha

Any captcha plugin for struts 2 other than jcaptcha4struts2 and provide some useful  link also

Comment: If you find any java captcha solution it shouldn't be too hard to implement with S2, I'm just saying you don't have to restrict yourself to plugins. What are the requirements for the captcha?

Comment: captcha image must be refreshed using refresh button

Comment: That's just a bit of JS. I personally found this useful, it asynchronously loads cat pictures http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: I created a new Servlet which act as captcha thanks everyone for sharing your ideas

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/recaptcha/docs/java.html

It is pretty straightforward with Struts 2.

I recommend you to copy over the source code (its ASL licensed and therefore allowed) and then follow the instructions. Or you create a taglib, if you would like to avoid java code in you jsp.

The server side instructions can be modified to use it with the field names recaptcha_challenge_field and recaptcha_response_field.

If you add the following methods to your action:

```
public HttpServletRequest getHttpServletRequest() {
    return httpServletRequest;
}

public void setHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
    this.httpServletRequest = httpServletRequest;
}
```

And add the following listener to web.xml:

```
 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

You are able to catch the HttpServletRequest which is necessary to validate the captcha.

Hope that helps.
Cheers,
Christian